# It smells like AJAX but I'm not sure

Tags: php, mysql, ajax, filter

AMENDMENT:

Hi all, thanks for all your replies. I've been wrestling trying to shoe horn the code into my page but I've still had no luck. While fiddling around I can't see why something like the below code wouldn't work - I can't get this to work either mind you(!). If it's not possible I'm hoping someone can shoot the idea down to save me wasting time trying to do it:

```
<form name='Names' role='form' action='#' method='get' onchange='this.form.submit()'>
    <select name="FirstName">
        <option value="1">FirstName#1</option>
    </select>
    <select name="LastName">
        <option value="1">LastName#1</option>
    </select>
</form>
```

...could I then pick up these selections in `$_GET['FirstName']` and `$_GET['LastName']` and pass them into my mysqli_query() to generate the table?

---

To prevent any chance of my confusion spreading I first want to describe what I'm trying to do... I want a webpage that has a table with a group of dropdowns that I can filter on - similar to Excel filters. If you know of a better way of doing it than how I'm trying below - please do enlighten me!!

Now, to describe the best progress I've made so far:

I have the below script (copied straight over from W3schools:

```
<script>
    function showUser(str) {
      if (str=="") {
        document.getElementById("txtHint").innerHTML="";
        return;
      } 
      if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {
        // code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
        xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
      } else { // code for IE6, IE5
        xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
      }
      xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function() {
        if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200) {
          document.getElementById("txtHint").innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;
        }
      }
      xmlhttp.open("GET","entry_table.php?q="+str,true);
      xmlhttp.send();
    }
</script>
```

The above script is called from the below dropdown which populated using a PHP while loop from an SQL query:

```
<form>
    <select name="Name" onchange="showUser(this.value)">
        <option value="1">User#1</option>
    </select>
</form>
```

The $q value is then passed to a PHP page to display the table after generating the SQL query with a:

`WHERE UserID="$q"`

This works but I'm concerned it seems to be a long-winded way of doing it - especially if I'm try to and expand the queries to include 6-7 other dropdown filters.

Thanks in advance,
Ben

Comment: It doesn't only smell as ajax, but it also tastes as ajax. It is ajax and no, it is not a "long" way to do that, it's just ajax and, as long as you don't use jQuery, this is probably the way to do this. Just be careful to sql injections though, sanitize the value in your php script before executing the query.

Comment: Why shouldn't he use jQuery?

Comment: @DavidJones: Did I say he shouldn't? I just said that, as long as he DOESN'T use it, it probably is the way to go. I mean: if he does not use jquery this is probably the best he can do, else, by using jQuery, it will be shorter :P

Comment: @briosheje Ok, I agree jQuery would be shorter

Comment: Thanks guys - I'll take a look at jQuery then... I'm trying to learn best practices as I go as I'm new to all this (and thanks for the comment on sanitising the values first - will do that now :) )

Comment: @DavidJones: Any chance you could offer a jQuery solution to compare against please?? :) I have read that if there's a jQuery solution it's usually the most efficient way of achieving something...?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could go for a callback function instead.

```
function getData(url, callback)
{
    if (window.XMLHttpRequest) 
    {
        //IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
        xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
    } 
    else 
    { //IE6, IE5
        xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
    }
    xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function() 
    {
        if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200) 
        {
            callback(xmlhttp.responseText);
        }
    }

    xmlhttp.open("GET", url, true);
    xmlhttp.send(); 
}
```

And then make an ajax call like this:

```
getData("entry_table.php?q="+str, function(data)
{
    document.getElementById("txtHint").innerHTML=data;
});
```

Outer function

```
function doStuff(value) {
    getData("entry_table.php?q="+value, function(data)
    {
        document.getElementById("txtHint").innerHTML=data;
    });
}
```

and then select would be

```
<select onchange="doStuff(this.value)">
```

Comment: Thanks Seunhaab - am I right in thinking the callback function will then pass the $q value back to the same page to generate the table?

Comment: It will pass back whatever result you get from entry_table to the callback function as a parameter, which is the "function(data)". Then you can access it as data in that function.

Comment: Thanks for following up @Seunhaab - I've no doubt your code works but I'm still trying to get it working in my program. I'm new to ajax/javascript and am struggling to work out which bits go where... Your getData call - dos that go in the <form><select> section with an onchange= event as well? or somewhere else?

Comment: I usually write an outer function that calls the getData method, that way my inline eventhandler attribute only contains the function. Check the edit of my answer for an example.

Comment: Thanks Seunhaab - I haven't managed to nail it yet but I can see it all makes sense...just have to find the bit of my code that doesn't! :oP

Comment: Is it javascript that's letting you down? You can check the console for errors when you right-click inspect element.

Comment: No I'm not getting any errors - the initial page loads fine but when I select anything from the dropdowns there's no $_GET values being passed over...so I think it's my lack of understanding of the process that's letting me down. I have used your code and just made the following changes: `document.getElementById("FirstName")` (to match the `name=` in my <select> and `getData("store.php?q="+str, function(data)` (to point back to the 'self' page) ....everything else I have left untouched - any idea what I could be doing wrong? :-/

Comment: Whatever element you put in here:

    document.getElementById("txtHint").innerHTML=data;

Is going to be filled with our data from the ajax call, so give that the name your textbox carries. Check out my newly updated answer to see how the value from select is passed to the function.

Comment: Hi Seunhaab (and all), just to let you know - I managed to get the table populated in the end - although must admit I didn't get it working with Ajax in the end. I did the `<form onchange='this.form.submit()>` and then passed the $_POST array to the dropdown menus (and populated the `SELECTED` keyword on the value of the posted select item. Thanks for al your support :)